# CoCreateInstance of OLE control failed

Tags: visual-studio-2012, com, activex

I inherited a visual studio 6 project that uses Thorlab activex controls.
The project used to run on windows XP a couple of years ago and I have managed to import it and build it in VS2012.
The problem is, when I try to run the exe file, I get a:

```
"Debug Assertion Failed", file occcont.cpp line 925.
```

Looking at the VS output I see this:

```
"CoCreateInstance of OLE control {3CE35BF3-1E13-4D2C-8C0B-DEF6314420B3} failed.
>>> Result code: 0x80040154
>>> Is the control is properly registered?"
```

Reading other related posts, the error seems to indicate that the control is not registered and looking in the register I found that {3CE35BF3-1E13-4D2C-8C0B-DEF6314420B3} corresponds exactly to the Thorlabs MG17motor control.

I have tried to use regsvr32 to register again the control but I am pretty sure that they are, since I can use the activeX in matlab.

My question is, why is the compiled code failing to see the control?
Could it be that the problem is that this machine is 64bit and so is the activex server, while the code was written on a 32bit machine?
Is there a way to tell VS: "look, the activex control that will be running is this"?

I am really lost here and this is my first time dealing with activex controls in VS, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on a 64-bit machine, then if the CLSID is in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID then, it's a 64-bit control.  If the CLSID is in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID, then it's a 32-bit control.  64 bit processes aren't going to be able to use 32-bit DLLs, and vice versa.

If you have ported the project to VS 2012 already, why not build it to 64-bits if the control is 64-bits?

You have to either get the control in your desired architecture, or you have to build your project to the same architecture as the control.

Comment: Ho Joe, thanks for the answer. The control is indeed in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID so it is a 64bit control (I installed the 64-bit package from Thorlabs). How do I build to 64-bits then?

Comment: Your comment was really useful and I managed to solve the problem: I did not realize that I had to tell VS to compile for 64 machines. I re-compiled all the libraries needed in the project, in order to have them 64-bit. Then I followed this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb4317s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx to make VS compile the correct version and now the code is running. Thank you for the input.